# Rxjs, Observable chaining

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to use flatMap(), but it doesn't work.

```
var source1 = Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        observer.onNext(1);
        observer.onCompleted();
    }, 1000);
});

var source2 = Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        observer.onNext(2);
        observer.onCompleted();
    }, 1000);
});

var test = source1.flatMap((result) => {
    console.log('flat: ' + result);
    return source2;
}, e => console.log(`onError1: ${e}`)); // onError1: 1

test.subscribe((result) => {
    console.log('subscribe: ' + result);
}, e => console.log(`onError2: ${e}`)); // onError2: undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument of `flatMap` is [resultSelector](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/flatmap.html#arguments), not a error handler.

There is error handler at subscribe()'s second argument.

So your code should be like this:

```
...

var test = source1.flatMap((result) => {
    console.log('flat: ' + result);
    return source2;
});

...
```